# Update text input from select option chosen

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a select field which also updates a text field when chosen with the price of that selected option. Any Ideas on why this wont work?

Html:

```
<label for="material1" class="select">Material:</label>
<select name="material" id="material1" data-native-menu="false" rel="price1">
<option>Select Material</option>
<option value="55 Bolt" rel="125,000.00">55 Bolt</option>
</select>
<label for="net1">Net Price:</label>
<input type="text" name="net" id="net1" rel="price1" value=""  />
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("material1").change(function () {
   $(this).next("input[rel="+$(this).attr("rel")+"]").val($(this).val());
   $('#net1').textinput('refresh');

}).change();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is here, and **mgoeppner** has some good suggestions too.

```
$(this).next("input[rel="+$(this).attr("rel")+"]").val($(this).val());
```

`$(this).val()` refers to the value of `select` which is null. You have to refer to the value of the selected option. Then `next()` won't work because the `input` is not next to the `select`, there's a `label` in between. You can use `closest()`

```
var value = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
$(this).closest("input[rel="+$(this).attr("rel")+"]").val(value);
```

Comment: I added this to jsfiddle jsfiddle.net/7dSZm trying both of your options does not seem to work? –

Comment: You have a few syntax errors there and if you follow my example it works, look http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/7dSZm/2/

Comment: that shows the value of the selection, not the price fom the rel tag which is what i need.

Comment: Just change it to `attr('rel')`. I mean, try to understand the code, it's pretty basic stuff... http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/7dSZm/6/

Comment: You are right man, its been a long day sorry to trouble you. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

It won't work for a few reasons:

1. `$(this).next()` will return `[]` since the next sibling `<label>` is not an input with the a matching rel attribute. Try using `$(this).siblings("input[rel="+$(this).attr("rel")+"]")` instead.
2. There is no `textinput()` function in the jQuery API. Perhaps you meant `text()`?

Finally, you don't need to do `$(...).change(function()...).change()` -- `$(...).change(function()...)` will suffice .

Comment: This is jquery mobile, the refresh is something their code calls for to update the fields as they use a css class on top of the form fields. The label is also part of their code. I'll try your suggestions and see what happens.

Comment: Still no go, Here is what i did: I tried this: $(this).siblings("input[rel="+$(this).attr("rel")+"]").val($(this).val());

Comment: and I tried:    $(this).siblings("input[rel="+$(this).attr("rel")+"]");

Comment: You want the value of the selected option, see the bottom of elclanrs's answer for an example.

Comment: I added this to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7dSZm/ trying both of your options does not seem to work?

Comment: You forgot the correct CSS selector(#) for your change event, plus some more -- http://jsfiddle.net/yBcVK/2/